# Varying vibration frequencies

Tags: frequency, vibrations

Im currently testing vibrations through materials. I have a vibration motor that runs 200hz. Problem; the pressure I apply to the motor change the frequencies I pick up. Why?

Example: If I use a clamp to attach the motor to whatever Im testing, i measure 200hz. If I use manual pressure, the force I apply heavily influence the measured frequency. It was my understanding that a change in pressure would only influence the measured energy/amplitude of the signal, not lowering the frequency. Especially when testing softer materials or composites of materials. Sometimes I get measures that are 1/3 of input frequency. Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably changing the load on the motor.  Vibe tables typically are designed with mass >> max rated test mass.

Comment: The motor is a tiny shaftless piezo vibration motor, so I dont see exactly how the load would affect the input frequency into the pipe. It might though, thats why I came to 'physics'. In any case, wouldnt higher load = lower frequency? As if your are constraining its speed?
Edit: The motor datasheet doesnt present a load/hz chart.